# SpringMVC: do RequestMapping, GetMapping, PostMapping... have a common superclass?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```java
    public static void printPaths(RequestMapping mapping) {
        System.out.println(String.join(",",mapping.path()));
    }
```

the following code cannot work. Interestingly, stack overflow respondents will not read the question carefully before disproving of it.

```java
        final GetMapping getMapping = method.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
        printPaths(getMapping);
```

is there a type X when I use it like this:

```java
    public static void printPaths(X mapping) {
        System.out.println(String.join(",",mapping.path()));
    }
```

the following code can work well?

```java
        //WhateverMapping means it could be RequestMapping, or GetMapping, or PostMapping, or .....
        final WhateverMapping whateverMapping = method.getAnnotation(WhateverMapping.class);
        printPaths(whaterverMappingMapping);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do they have the same super class? It seems like you can find that out in a few seconds. I am not sure what your question is. This is not valid Java code.

Comment: I'm sorry that I cannot express myself clearly...emmmm, "do they have a common interface" may make the problem more clear? @tdranv

Comment: Yes, [GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) & [PostMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html) are shortcuts for [RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

Comment: @tdranv I upated my problem, is it more clear? thanks.

Comment: I feel like that it needs to be clarified how this website works. This is not Wikipedia you don’t just ask questions you come here with problems in code and show us what you have tried so far - for such questions please refer to Spring documentation

Comment: @JAsgarov I've searched, but it looks like there is no such thing.

Comment: @JAsgarov do you read the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as @GetMapping is a composed annotation, there is no superclass. A workaround is to use only @RequestMapping as @GetMapping is just a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method=GET).

```
GetMapping mapping = method.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
System.out.println(mapping instanceof RequestMapping); // false
```